# Using .net core and razor, how do I navigate back from a static page to the asp menu

Tags: asp.net, razor, navigation, asp.net-core-mvc

I have successfully implemented static pages in asp.net core in the wwwroot folder.

I can navigate to those pages using the _layout menu.

How do I navigate back from the static page to my asp.net razor home (index) page?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example.

[image]

In your `_layout`.

```
 <li class="nav-item">
     <a href="~/Test.html" class="nav-link text-dark">Test</a>
 </li>
```

Test.html:

```
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<a href="/home/index">Back</a>
</body>
```

Test Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response - but no joy.

I have tried the html file at various points in the wwwroot structure.  This variant matches the suggestion:
[Snip of wwwroot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AuQG.png)

I always manage to get to the html page on which I have:

[[Back to site](/home/index.cshtml)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWJMw.png)

I have tried all sorts of variants (again) including adding /Pages/, leaving out the 'cshtml' and ../ when in lower directories in wwwroot.

I am using net core 5 and Razor pages.

Any more suggestions?